# Redirect 301 domain and some pages

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, seo

I need a redirect with htaccess my old-domain.com to new-domain.com

The new domain have different urls

`old-domain.com/aboutus.html` to `new-domain.com/us.html`

`old-domain.com/contact-us.html` to `new-domain.com/form.html`

.....
.....

And all another pages old-domain.com/xxxxxxxxxxx redirect to home page new-domain.com

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your tried htaccess rule file in your question, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using an apache http server, you need to enable the rewriting module in your http server and you need to implement these rewriting rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?aboutus\.html$ /us.html [R=301,END]
RewriteRule ^/?contact-us\.html$ /form.html [R=301,END]
RewriteRule ^ / [R=301,END]
```

The rules can be placed in the host configuration of your http server. If you have no access to that you will have to use a distributed configuration file (".htaccess") which should be placed inside the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder of your http host. Keep in mind that you need to enable the interpretation of such files in that case, check the `AllowOverride` directive in the documentation of the apache http server.